# Request.UrlReferrer null but can see it in the browser request headers

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to save the referer when it's available but it seems to work inconsistently.

In Chrome, I Google the page I'm going to and click on it. In the developer tools I can see the referer has been set in the request headers.

[image: Request headers]

However Request.UrlReferrer is sometimes null. When I debug it locally, it's always available but when I push it to our test server, it seems hit and miss.

Are there any reasons why?

Comment: Referer can be null if you visit the page directly (from the address bar rather than clicking a link).

Comment: Yea, which is ok, but this is happening when I click on a link on Google and can see the referer has been set.

Comment: Is this always on the same page? Referer can be lost if any sort of redirect   happens on the site.